# How to run a program in background?

Tags: node.js, terminal

I have a node.js application. I want to run it in the background without keeping the terminal always open.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is loosely called "daemonizing" as in "turning it into a daemon process" and there are many tools that do this easily found on NPM if you know the keywords to search for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either PM2 process manager (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

Or You can use forever (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Or simply you can use nohup as

```
nohup node index.js &
```

This will run the node process in detached form in the background

Answer (score 0):

you need pm2.js;

goto [PM2 Quick Start](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)